# Copy From MemoryStream to another - Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, memorystream

I wanted to know if there might be a memory leak issue with the following code and how to solve it.

```
 MemoryStream stream_medium_temp = new MemoryStream();
 ms_medium.Position = 0;
 ms_medium.CopyTo(stream_medium_temp);
```

I want to copy a stream to another stream. I first created the stream_medium_temp instance which already have memory allocated for it. Now I copy a stream into it. Does it mean that the memory space that was allocated when I initialized the stream_medium_temp is not disposed properly, and if so, how do I encounter this in the code.

The stream_medium_temp is disposed inside a function in which it is passed by reference. My concern is about the memory allocation when the stream is first initialized for stream_medium_temp and after I copy a stream to it.

Let me give you an example:

**stream_medium_temp get initialized -> Memory allocated 1-50 (for example).
stream_medium_temp get stream copy to it -> memory allocated 60-110**

If that what happens, how to dispose the 1-50 memory allocation?

Thanks.

Comment: Which code creates `ms-medium`?

Comment: The ms_medium is dispose with using statement. The only concern that I have is with the stream_medium_temp being initialized and then copied to

Comment: A MemoryStream doe snot really need a Dispose (it's just a good practice). Just manage your reference like with any other data-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, assuming both MemoryStreams are eventually disposed, via `using` or via `.Dipose()`.

You don't have to manually manage the memory allocated by an `IDisposable` object - that's what `using` and/or `Dispose()` is for.

Note that `MemoryStream` actually does not allocate any resources that need disposing, and therefore doesn't technically need to be disposed. But it inherits from `Stream`, which implements `IDisposable`; therefore, it's `IDisposable` too, and it's good practice to dispose anything `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks, I asked a newbie question, and thanks for clarifying it up for me

Comment: A MemoryStream is not a resource in any way. Just a lump of memory.

Comment: @Henk, true. Added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Well while you copy the data then the original data is still existing.

I would suggest you to delete the data while copying it over if you do not want both instances of the data to exist.

Comment: Thanks, but how? Can you give a code example please.

Comment: He says "The ms_medium is dispose with using statement", so it sounds like he is doing that anyway.